# In a Java servlet running in GAE Flex, how do I get the containing GCP project ID programatically?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am writing a web service (java servlet) in the flexible environment of Google App Engine and I would like to be able to retrieve the GCP project ID that I am running in at runtime programatically.  How?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `SystemProperty` which contains such thins as project id, app version, etc:

```
SystemProperty.applicationId.get()
```

Javadoc is here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty

Comment: Does this work in the flexible environment?  Can you point me to the docs or maven coordinates?

Comment: yes, it does work in the flexible env. i've updated answer with a link to the javadoc

Comment: I didn't think we are supposed to use any java package that has "com.google.appengine." in it in the flexible environment.

Comment: why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

`SystemProperty` is a part of `com.google.appengine.api` which is not available on App Engine Flex environment.

On Flex your project name is available as environment variable.
So you simply can use just this:

```
System.getenv("GCLOUD_PROJECT");
```

Please see [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating) for more details.

Also please note that on local development server running Jetty this environment variable might not be set. If so the above code will return `null` on your development machine.

You might want to set it explicitly though for your local development server needs. For example if you use Bash you can do:

`export GCLOUD_PROJECT=myproject`

Also you can add it to your development server startup script or to your ~/.bashrc script, whatever works better for your needs.